# Making sense of multiplication in tensor product

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $\mathbb{Z} / p$ and $\mathbb{Z} / q$ be $\mathbb{Z} /pq$ modules where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. Then $\mathbb{Z}/p \times \mathbb{Z}/q$ is a $\mathbb{Z} / pq$ module

Now let $$ i : \mathbb{Z}/p \times \mathbb{Z} / q \to \mathbb{Z}/p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/pq} \mathbb{Z} /q$$ be a bilinear map from the direct sum to the tensor product.

Then each tensor monomial $m \otimes n \in \mathbb{Z}/p \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}/pq} \mathbb{Z} /q$ is the image, $i(m,n)$, that is, $i(m,n)= m \otimes n$.

An example I am reading uses the following multiplication, since $(p,q)=1$, there exists $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $rq + sp =1$.

Consider, $$ (rq + sp)(m \otimes n)$$

It really only makes sense to multiple $m \otimes n$ by an element of $\mathbb{Z} /pq$. I know that $1 \in \mathbb{Z} /pq$ and we have the above equality for $1$ but multiplying by $rp +sq$ is still a bit sketchy for me.

I am not sure how to make sense of this equation $1=rp+sq$ inside $\mathbb{Z} /pq$ and thus I feel apprehensive about this multiplication.

Can anyone clarify why multiplying by $rp+sq$ is valid?

Comment: (i) Why are you calling $\Bbb Z/p\times\Bbb Z/q$ a tensor product? (ii) Any abelian group is automatically a $\Bbb Z$-module - you just use repeated addition and additive inverses - so of course you can make sense of the expression $(rq+sp)(m\otimes n)$. By the way, that's an *expression*, not an *equation*. Equations equate expressions using equals signs.

Comment: Sorry my question was a bit vague. I was referring to the equation, $1=rp +sq$.

Comment: You can either interpret that in $\Bbb Z$ or interpret it in $\Bbb Z/pq$ using residues, as we frequently do (although the latter isn't even necessary, since $rp+sq=1$ in $\Bbb Z$ is perfectly sufficient). By the way, are you missing an $=m\otimes n$ after $(rq+sp)(m\otimes n)$ in your question?

Comment: It didn't seem necessary to write $= m \otimes n$ since I was only asking about the validity of the multiplication itself.

Comment: In any additively-written abelian group $M$ you can multiply by integers - by definition it means repeated addition (with additive inverses if the integer is negative). That is, $$nx:=\begin{cases}\overbrace{x+\cdots+x}^n & \textrm{if } n>0 \\[5pt] 0_M & \textrm{if }n=0 \\[5pt] \underbrace{(-x)+\cdots+(-x)}_{-n} & \textrm{if }n<0 \end{cases} $$ where $0_M$ is $M$'s additive identity and $-x$ is $x$'s additive inverse in $M$. In this way, $M$ will be a $\Bbb Z$-module (so $(n+m)x=nx+mx$ and $n(mx)=(nm)x$ for all $n,m\in\Bbb Z$, $x\in M$).